# Image with disks of increasing size

Tags: image-processing

I would like to produce a **black image with superposed white disks**.

- The disk centers should start from the lower left and end at the upper right position.
- The disk size should increase lineary from lower left to upper right position.

What I tried:

```
n = 400;
imageData = Array[0 &, {n, n}];
image = Image[imageData];


array = Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, n}]; 
objects = Table[Image@DiskMatrix[i/10 // N], {i, 1, n, 1}];

ImageCompose[image, objects, array]
```

Result:

[image]

As you see this the diagonal is not white.

My expected results should be:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient to use Disk / Table / Rasterize?

Comment: @Kuba: Could you please show a code snipplet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
Graphics[{White, Table[
   Disk[{i, i}, .2 i],
   {i, 10}]}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If, for some reason, you want to do this with arrays and images instead of `Graphics`, you can use [`InverseDistanceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseDistanceTransform.html) to turn a 2d array of radii into an image of overlapping discs:

```
dist = Image[
  SparseArray[Table[{5 i, 5 i} -> i, {i, 1, 20, 5}], {100, 100}]]
```

[image]

```
InverseDistanceTransform[dist]
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

another approach, close to the original. `ImageCompose` one disk at a time then `ImageMultiply` the results.  For this to work we need to work in negative images, so you start with a white "canvas" and multiply by black (0) disks. (then negate the final result)

```
imageData = Array[1 &, {n, n}];
image = Image[imageData];
array = Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, n, 20}];
objects = 
  Table[ColorNegate@Image@(DiskMatrix[i/10 // N]), {i, 1, n, 20}];
ColorNegate@
 ImageMultiply[image, 
  Sequence @@ (MapThread[
     ImageCompose[image, ##] &, {objects, array}])]
```

[image]

I expect you can see in the original form `ImageCompose` was covering prior white disks with the black border of the next disk image.  To illustrate, colorize the black part of the individual disk images:

```
objects = Table[ColorReplace[Image@DiskMatrix[i/10 // N],
    0 -> Hue[RandomReal[{0, 2/3}]]], {i, 1, n, 20}];
ImageCompose[image, objects, array]
```

[image]